# Scanf not working in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am learning objective-C and I am stumped at this point where a very simple scanf statement is not working.

I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong and I had already spent an hour on this but no avail.

Could anyone take a look at this? I am talking about the second scanf which when the operator1 == B

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Calculator+Trig.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    float val1, val2;
    char operator1;
    char operator2;
    char operator3;

    Calculator *deskCalc = [[Calculator alloc] init];


    NSLog(@"Please choose the type of operations:");
    NSLog(@"A) ---> Arithmatic");
    NSLog(@"B) ---> Trigonometric");
    scanf("%c", &operator1);
    NSLog(@"the operator is %c", operator1);




    if (operator1 == 'B') {
        NSLog(@"Type in your expression:");
        scanf("%c %f", &operator2, &val1);
        NSLog(@"The value of accumulator is %f", val1);

        deskCalc.accumulator = val1;
        NSLog(@"The value of accumulator is %f", val1);
        switch (operator2) {
            case '+':
                NSLog(@"The operator is sin");
                break;

            default:
                NSLog(@"Invalid operator");
                break;
        }
    }


    else if (operator1 == 'A'){
    NSLog(@"Type in your expression:");
    scanf("%f %c %f", &val1, &operator3, &val2);

    deskCalc.accumulator = val1;
        NSLog(@"The value of accumulator is %f", val1);


    switch (operator3) {
        case '+':
            [deskCalc add:val2];
            break;
        case '-':
            [deskCalc subtract:val2];
            break;
        case '*':
            [deskCalc multiply:val2];
            break;
        case '/':
            [deskCalc divide:val2];
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown operator");
            break;
    }
    }
    NSLog(@"The value is %0.2f", deskCalc.accumulator);

}
return 0;
}
```

My console output if anyone is wondering

```
2014-03-06 18:56:23.277 Calculator[723:303] Please choose the type of operations:
2014-03-06 18:56:23.278 Calculator[723:303] A) ---> Arithmatic
2014-03-06 18:56:23.279 Calculator[723:303] B) ---> Trigonometric
B
2014-03-06 18:56:24.656 Calculator[723:303] the operator is B 
2014-03-06 18:56:24.656 Calculator[723:303] Type in your expression: 
+ 30.0
2014-03-06 18:56:28.852 Calculator[723:303] The value of accumulator is 0.000000
2014-03-06 18:56:28.853 Calculator[723:303] The value of accumulator is 0.000000
2014-03-06 18:56:28.853 Calculator[723:303] Invalid operator
2014-03-06 18:56:28.854 Calculator[723:303] The value is 0.00
```

Comment: Can you define "not working"?

Comment: where do you run your app or better how? from Xcode or from the terminal?

Comment: @PhillipMills  I added my console output.

Comment: @Volker I use Xcode, the 'A' option is working fine.

Comment: i am not sure if the Xcode console is well for scant... have you tried compiling and running the executable from the command line aka terminal.app?

Comment: The option for B works for me pasting the code into XCode and running in Terminal.app, so that should resolve the issue.

Comment: @dmason82 could you please help me with the terminal app building?I tried using xcodebuild but I'm getting unknown build action.

Comment: Was that from the top level of your xcode project folder? Or where are you in terminal when you try to invoke it?

Comment: This is what I am doing `XYZ@BBC:~/Desktop/stephen Kochan obj-C/12/Calculator$ xcodebuild Calculator.xcodeproj`

Comment: You would want to use xcodebuild -project  Calculator.xcodeproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%c", &operator1);
```

reads one character, but not he *newline* character that you typed. Therefore you should replace

```
scanf("%c %f", &operator2, &val1);
```

by

```
scanf(" %c %f", &operator2, &val1);
```

(note the initial space character). Otherwise the `%c` will read this newline character
into `operator2`.

Alternatively, consider to use `fgets()`, which reads an entire line (including the newline)
into a string buffer, and then parse the string buffer.